# Adding backend errors to myFormItem.$error without invalidating form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I'm using ng-messages to show various validation messages for a component, like so:

```
<ng-messages for="myForm.myField.$error" ng-if="myForm.myField.$touched">
    <ng-message when="required">My Field required</ng-message>
    <ng-message when="foo">Foo Message</ng-message>
    <ng-message when="backend">{{myForm.backendMessages.myField}}</ng-message>
</ng-messages>
```

During handling of error messages from the server, I'm adding the customised error messages to the component:

```
myField.$setValidity("backend", false);
myField.$setTouched(true); // So ng-messages is shown
```

Which is working fine insofar as putting the messages where I want them, but this obviously marks the form as "invalid", which means I can't use simple logic to disable form submission when the client-side validations are triggered.

Is there a "blessed" way I can add to `myField.$error` without actually invalidating the component and form? Or must I reset the entirety of the "valid" flags once the user dirties the form, which will make the message disappear? If the latter, what's the nicest way to do this?

Using Angular 1.4.1 FWIW.

Comment: confused...what exactly you are looking for
?

Comment: Ideally a way to get things into $error without having to mark a field as invalid, in a manner that won't get splatted as soon as the client-side validations are run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm haven't used the `ng-messages` component yet but sounds like using the `novalidate` attribute could work.

```
<form method="POST" action="xyz" novalidate> ... </form>
```

This way the component validates and the browser won't trigger native validation errors

Comment: No, it's unrelated to that.